# Call to undefined function openssl_decrypt

Tags: php, openssl, php-openssl

When I try to make a request with POST to a script that has this line:

```
$decrypted_data = openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, 'AES-256-CBC', $key);
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  openssl_decrypt() in mypath/usuario_webservice.php on line 11

After some research the common reasons would be entering the wrong name for the function or the openssl extension not being installed on my web server. It turns out that it is installed as I checked with the support. So, what else should I be looking for?

Comment: What php version is installed on the web-server? you need php 5.3+

Comment: `"It turns out that it is installed as I checked with the support."` Maybe support doesn't know what they're talking about. Make a PHP page with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, run it, and look through it to see for yourself whether its installed or not.

Comment: the openssl module needs to be both installed AND activated. Support probably just confirmed that it's installed but never checked that it's turned on, use `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and see if the module is in fact being used.

Comment: @jeroen the version we got here is 5.2.17. I might have misunderstood but the documentation says I could use it from php 4.3.2. I read it here.
http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.requirements.php

Comment: Not according to this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php. Note that this is specific to the function you are trying to use.

Comment: @iamde_coder I got both the --with-openssl in Configure Command and  OpenSSL support enabled in OpenSSL section. Where could I check this activation?

Comment: @jeroen Well maybe this is it then. So it is possible to have support for the extension but not for some specific methods?

Comment: @CJ_COIMBRA Ask the support if they can upgrade your php version to 5.4, since 5.4 is already stable.

Comment: Copying libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll from PHP-root folder to Apache/bin folder and restarted Apache solved my problem.

Answer (score 15):

I am posting this as it might be helpful to some.

- Check `extension=php_openssl.dll` is enabled in your `php.ini`.
- Check `extension_dir` is pointed correctly in `php.ini`.

If you have recently upgraded your php version and not your Apache then it might be a possibility that correct `libeay32.dll`and `ssleay32.dll` are not being read which is a requirement for openssl or some version mismatch is happening.

- Get latest version of `libeay32.dll`and `ssleay32.dll` or copy it from your php directory say `C:\php` and overwrite the files in your Apache\bin say `C:\Apache24\bin` directory.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I download latest libeay32 and ssleay32 dll and restart apache and it works, thanks

Comment: For those who are still looking into this, note that since version 1.1.0, the library names have changed. libeay32.dll becomes libcrypto-1_1.dll and ssleay32.dll becomes libssl-1_1.dll. As indicated in this answer, both files should be in your PHP directory.

Answer (score 3):

Enable this extension in your **php.ini** file by removing semicolon

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Restart your **Apache** server and retry
Hope that helps :)

Comment: OP had to contact support, so I'm assuming he is having this problem on the hosting server, and may not have access to the php.ini file (depending on the type of hosting they have) so this post may prove to be incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

i had this problem so i just used Crypt_AES by phpseclib:

```
<?php
include('Crypt/AES.php');

$cipher = new Crypt_AES(); // it's cbc by default
$cipher->setKeyLength(256);
$cipher->setKey('abcdefghijklmnopijklmnopqrstuvwxyz3456');

$size = 10 * 1024;
$plaintext = str_repeat('a', $size);

echo $cipher->decrypt($cipher->encrypt($plaintext));
?>
```

Comment: I´ll take a look today.

Comment: Is this compatible with the encryption from OpenSSL? It is important to be able to decrypt data on one machine that was encrypted on another.

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me is upgrading Apache from 2.4.27 to  2.4.53.

I am using Wampserver 3.2.8 on Win64.
php_openssl was on in all ini files.

Answer (score 0):

I  decided that the problem was reinstalling xampp to the latest version, I don’t know why, but the xampp version went through and I was constantly getting an error